# How can i read in Java an HSQL data base built using libreoffice?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hsqldb

My problem is that I am trying to make a connection using Java (using Eclipse) to a local database. I don't want to use a remote database because I dont want to setup a server and also because my aplication doesn't need a remote DB.

I dont'have Microsoft Access, so I created the database using LibreOffice. What I know is that LibreOffice is the interface that allows you to create a database, and it can be set up using another database infrastructure like Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

I decided to download the driver HSQLDB.jar and I installed it in Eclipse.

The following code shows you my example:

```
   String db="C:\\Users\\Alberto\\Documents\\Peluqueria.odb";

    try {  
        // Cargamos el controlador JDBC  
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");  
    } catch (Exception ex){  
        System.err.println("Se pa producido un error al cargar el controlador JDBC");  
        return;  
    }  

    // Nos conectamos a la base de datos creándola en caso de que no exista   
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:"+db,"sa",""); 

    Statement statement=conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TB_Servicios");

    while (rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
```

The Error Exception i get is:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: TB_SERVICIOS
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at Formularios.VentantaTabla.<init>(VentantaTabla.java:69)
at Formularios.VentantaTabla$1.run(VentantaTabla.java:31)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
     Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o
     objeto no encontrado: TB_SERVICIOS
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you, but at the end I discovered the solution. The problem is that when I create a database using OpenOffice, the file is with extension ".odb" and this file is compressed.

So if I want to connect to the database I have to decompress the file first and later I have to use the right driver to work out the connection.

I hope it helps you

Comment: Your blog is in spanish. Please add a brief explanation in this answer.

Comment: It's true, my post is in spanish, but if you are a programmer, you wouldn't have any trouble to understand the code which is in written in english. However, I invite you to learn spanish as i have done with the english

Comment: I tried but I am not even sure that I am on the right blogpost. :-)

Comment: Also, I have learned english and german, am native swedish swedish speaker. :-) I don't need a fourth language since I'm not very good at them.

Comment: A link isn't useful if you don't put the highlights in your answer (read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), even worse if it isn't in English. Maybe you want to go to http://spanish.stackexchange.com/ if you are more comfortable with Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

You have not completed the database creation part with LibreOffice.

After creating the database in LibreOffice, you need to export a script of the database by running the direct statement `SCRIPT 'file_path_name.script'`. You then connect from your program to `jdbc:hsqldb:file:file_path_name`

You cannot connect to an `.odb` file directly.

Comment: ohh, it looks interesting and it makes sense. I will try your solution just to see another alternative to mine. Thank you anyway

Comment: Script must be fed the absolute path to the script. A relative path will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not understand Spanish but I translated the error message from your log file

> usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado

as following:

> user does not have sufficient privilege or object not found

Now we can understand exactly what the error messages says. You either do not have permissions to select from table `TB_Servicios` or such table does not exist. 
Since you are using user account `sa` (that means "system administrator") and your connection established successfully I can assume that you have all permissions you need. Therefore the only one possibility is that the table does not exist in your database.

Have you created table `TB_Servicios`? If not check how to create it in manual of you DB. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the table was created, the problem was that the file is compressed. That is why i have that error message